# Successful swap in Main of a and b

Tags: c

**Not swapping a and 5 in main. I am assuming something with the pointers is off. What would be the changes to get the values to change in main? Currently it does the following when printed:
**

```
a= 5
b= 10
a= 10
b= 5
a= 5
b= 10


void swap (int* a, int* b) {
    int c = 0 ;
    c = a ;
    a = b ;
    b = c ;

    printf ("a= %d\n", a) ;
    printf ("b= %d\n", b) ;

    return ;
}

int main(){
    int* a = 5 ;
    int* b = 10 ;

    printf ("a= %d\n", a) ;
    printf ("b= %d\n", b) ;

    swap (a,b) ;

    printf ("a= %d\n", a) ;
    printf ("b= %d\n", b) ;

    return (0) ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int* a = 5 ;
int* b = 10 ;
```

This should be:

```
int a = 5 ;
int b = 10 ;
```

Then you can use `swap(&a, &b)` to swap them, if you make these changes to your `swap` code:

```
c = *a ;
*a = *b ;
*b = c ;

printf ("a= %d\n", *a) ;
printf ("b= %d\n", *b) ;
```

This is a full example:

```
void swap (int* a, int* b) {
    int c = 0 ;
    c = *a ;
    *a = *b ;
    *b = c ;

    printf ("a= %d\n", *a) ;
    printf ("b= %d\n", *b) ;

    return ;
}

int main(){
    int a = 5 ;
    int b = 10 ;

    printf ("a= %d\n", a) ;
    printf ("b= %d\n", b) ;

    swap (&a,&b) ;

    printf ("a= %d\n", a) ;
    printf ("b= %d\n", b) ;

    return (0) ;

}
```

Comment: Can you put these in the code? Along with the types. I get errors when I made these initial changes